# Get hidden field value that came with ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

How can I check using jQuery or javascript a hidden field value that just came in html with ajax call? There must be something easy but cannot find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your ajax response is an HTML you can do this:

```
var hiddenValue = $('yourHiddenSelector', $(ajaxResponseHtml)).val();
```

for example if your ajax response is:

```
'<div class="container"><input type="hidden" value="3" id="myhidden" name="number"></div>'
```

Your code could be like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {},
    success: function(ajaxResponseHtml){
         var hiddenValue = $('#myhidden', $(ajaxResponseHtml)).val(); //output 3
    },
    error: function(){ alert('error');}
});
```

Comment: I don't understand why $() has 2 parameters and what is $(ajaxResponseHtml)?

Comment: See my edit, maybe I'm misunderstanding your question.